# Properties of Bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $K$ be a field, let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space, and let $f: V \times V \to K$ be a bilinear form. The bilinear form $f$ is called *non-degenerate* if the mapping $$V \to \operatorname{Hom}(V,K); \ v \mapsto (w \mapsto f(v,w))$$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces. Show that the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) $f$ is non-degenerate.

(ii) If $f(v,w) = 0$ for all $w ∈ V$, then $v = 0$.

(iii) There exists a basis $v_{1},\dots,v_{n}$ of $V$ such that the associated matrix $(f(v_{i}, v_{j}))_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ is invertible.

(iv) For every basis $v_{1},\dots,v_{n}$ of $V$, the associated matrix $(f(v_{i}, v_{j}))_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ is invertible.

I wonder what properties of bilinear form, $\operatorname{Hom}$, and isomorphism that need to be used here to prove those conditions?

Comment: what do you mean by $(v,w)=0$ in (ii)?

Comment: I guess the most important fact here that you can use is the following: if $V$ has a basis $\{v_1\ldots ,v_n\}$ then $Hom(V,k)$ has the dual basis $\{ v_1^*,\ldots ,v_n^*\}$ where $v_i^*(v_i)=1$ and $v_i^*(v_j)=0$ is $i\not =j$. The rest of the proof is essentially by definition.

Comment: In (ii) we are saying that $v \mapsto (w \mapsto f(v,w))$ is injective, so (i) and (ii) are equivalent (this is because $\operatorname{Hom}(V,K)$ has the same dimension as $V$, which is $n<\infty$).